AWS RDS MariaDB 10.6 instance crashed suddenly
My instance crashed randomly without any warning. The CloudWatch metrics were good until suddenly there was a gap.


The instance has general logging enabled and I checked the recent queries but didn't find anything suspicious prior to the crash. There was also no traffic spike. I also investigated the logs but couldn't find anything useful as well.
One thing I would like to rule out is hardware issue. How can I confirm without access to AWS Support?
